# Gatling: Consuming all values from a Collection (Feeder) in parallel

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I have a list of user ids, they can be stored in a Collection or Feeder.
In the test I create users with provided ids (around 2000 users) in one POST request and then send GET requests to verify that the users were created. It may take 5-10 seconds to create all the users, but first users start to appear after 0.5-1 second.
I am creating and verifying users simultaneously in two different scenarios. The problem is that verifyUsers(ids) will send GET requests for each id one by one, but I need them to be sent in parallel because each GET request will take some time and I don't want to create a queue.

```
def createUsers(ids: List[String]): ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Create users")
    .exec(createUsersForIds(ids))

def verifyUsers(ids: List[String]) = scenario("Verify users")
    .repeat(ids.size, "iterator") {
        exec(session => {
            val index: Int = session("iterator").as[Int]
            session.set("id", ids.take(index))
        })
            .exec(verifyUserWithId) // verifyUserWithId will then take a userId from the session and send a GET request with that id
    }

setUp(
    createUsers(ids).inject(atOnceUsers(1)),
    verifyUsers(ids).inject(atOnceUsers(1))
)
```

Comment: From what I see your setup is using one virtual user. Have you tried increasing the atOnceUsers(virtualUsers) to number higher than 1? You can have multiple requests in one scenario in case you need to perform operations one after another for the same context.

Comment: Yes, I think a solution will be to use several Gatling virtual users, however I can't figure out how to assign a unique id (from the ids: List[String]) to each virtual user, so that each virtual user will be verifying only one id.
Maybe I need to use a synchronized collection for storing ids, but I'm not sure how to pull it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you want multiple producers (virtual users in the `createUsers` scenario) and multiple consumers (virtual users in the `verifyUsers` scenario), with a queue in between.

Some hints:

- use a concurrent queue, such as `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue`
- use some counters such as `AtomicLong` to keep track of the number of records produced and consumed so you can detect when you've consumed all the records you've ultimately produced.
- implement the consumer side so that when there's no available records (possibly because you're consuming faster than you're producing), you do a loop (`asLongAs`) with a pause.

Edit:
If your use case is actually that the producer produces all records at once, the solution is way easier:

- make the producer and consumer scenarios sequential, see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/injection/#sequential-scenarios
- have all your consumers poll the concurrent queue in a loop (AslongAs or doWhile depending on how you implement your logic) as long as the polled record is not empty

Hope it helps!